# How to add encrypted swap file on FreeBSD 13

Tags: freebsd, encryption, swap

I want to add encrypted swap file in FreeBSD 13.

I have read [this](https://people.freebsd.org/%7Erodrigc/doc/handbook/adding-swap-space.html) documentation page, but it doesn't explain how to set up encryption for the swap file.

I've also read [another one](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/disks/#swap-encrypting), but it only gives examples for encrypted swap partitions, not swap file. The aim is to have encrypted swap file activated on system startup. The system runs latest FreeBSD 13.

Please explain how to achieve this.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: So, you want unencrypted storage, but encrypted swap. May I ask what that would be good for?

Comment: Hi Marcus, thanks for noting this. Your point may be valid, but sorry, I'm not going to discuss here the questions like you've asked above.

Comment: as said, it was just out of curiosity! I see you must have a system that stores nothing sensitive on non-volatile storage, and that sounded fancy :) (I'm well aware what you describe could well be used to exfiltrate RAM in an encrypted manner to obfuscate the fact you've taken a memory capture, but it's no sense beating around the bush with that.)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the solution is but in my attempts to find an answer I stumbled across some information which may be helpful: https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/encrypt-swap-file.44519/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link provided by `@r bert` is close, but could benefit from a little fine-tuning.

Credit to original creator [mb2015 on the FreeBSD forum](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/encrypt-swap-file.44519/).  This method creates a custom service script and establishes controlling parameters in `/etc/rc.conf`.

To begin, create `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/encrypted_swapfile` by copying and pasting this large `cat` command to execute it, and execute the `chmod` command following it:

```
# cat << 'EOF' > /usr/local/etc/rc.d/encrypted_swapfile
#!/bin/sh

# PROVIDE: encrypted_swapfile
# REQUIRE: swaplate
# BEFORE: LOGIN
# KEYWORD: nojail shutdown

. /etc/rc.subr

name="encrypted_swapfile"
rcvar="encrypted_swapfile_enable"

start_cmd="${name}_start"
stop_cmd="${name}_stop"

load_rc_config "$name"
: ${encrypted_swapfile_enable:="NO"}
: ${encrypted_swapfile_file:="/usr/swap0"}
: ${encrypted_swapfile_size:="2G"}

SWFILE="$encrypted_swapfile_file";
SWFILEDIR="$(dirname "$SWFILE")";
SWDEVLINK="/var/run/encrypted_swapfile_device";

encrypted_swapfile_start()
{
    # Create and mount a one-time encrypted swap file.
    # This is a workaround for the inability to do this via an /etc/fstab entry.
    # See https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/encrypt-swap-file.44519/#post-292933
    #
    if [ ! -e "$SWDEVLINK" ]; then
        if [ -w "$SWFILEDIR" ]; then
            truncate -s "$encrypted_swapfile_size" "$encrypted_swapfile_file" &&
            chmod 0600 "$encrypted_swapfile_file" &&
            SWMD="$(mdconfig -a -t vnode -f "$encrypted_swapfile_file")" &&
            if [ $? -eq 0 ] && [ -n $SWMD ] && [ -e "/dev/$SWMD" ]; then
                chmod 0600 "/dev/$SWMD" &&
                geli onetime -e AES-XTS -l 256 -d "/dev/$SWMD" &&
                chmod 0600 "/dev/$SWMD.eli" &&
                swapon "/dev/$SWMD.eli" &&
                ln -f -s "/dev/$SWMD.eli" "$SWDEVLINK";
                unset SWMD;
            fi
        else
            echo "Could not create encrypted swap file in $SWFILEDIR; check permissions." &&
            return 1;
        fi
    else
        SWMD="$(readlink "$SWDEVLINK")" &&
        swapinfo | grep -vq "^$SWMD " &&
        echo "Encrypted swap file already exists; enabling." &&
        swapon "$SWMD";
        unset SWMD;
    fi
    return 0;
}

encrypted_swapfile_stop()
{
    if [ -e "$SWDEVLINK" ]; then
        SWMD=$(readlink "$SWDEVLINK") &&
        swapoff "$SWDEVLINK" &&
        mdconfig -du "${SWMD%.eli}" &&
        rm "$SWDEVLINK" &&
        rm "$SWFILE";
    else
        echo "No encrypted swap file found; nothing to stop.";
        rm -f "$SWDEVLINK";
    fi
}

run_rc_command "$1"

EOF
# chmod 755 /usr/local/etc/rc.d/encrypted_swapfile
```

Next, edit `/etc/rc.conf` to enable this new service, and configure the variables it uses:

```
encrypted_swapfile_enable="yes"
encrypted_swapfile_file="/usr/swap0"
encrypted_swapfile_size="2G"
```

Now your encrypted swapfile can be activated or deactivated by starting or stopping the `encrypted_swapfile` service, respectively:

```
# swapinfo
Device          1024-blocks     Used    Avail Capacity
# service encrypted_swapfile start
# swapinfo
Device          1024-blocks     Used    Avail Capacity
/dev/md0.eli        2097152        0  2097152     0%
# service encrypted_swapfile stop
# swapinfo
Device          1024-blocks     Used    Avail Capacity
```

Comment: That's interesting. Thank you. I will try this and update here about how this have worked for me.

Comment: Thank you. I just tried this and it is working.